# Снятие резервов по заказу на МойСклад через json API

Tags: moysklad-json-api

Как правильно снять резерв  с заказа?

По идее логично было бы в изменении заказа `/entity/customerorder/{id}`, но там только `reservedSum`, которая доступна только для чтения.

Или вытаскивать все позиции заказа отдельно и проставлять каждой позиции резерв 0?

Answer (score 0):

Да, необходимо доставать все позиции заказа в одном запросе и во втором передавать их назад с reserve = 0. В не зависимости от того, какой способ резервирования(по товарно или весь заказ целиком) выбран в настройках Вашего МС.